# ncurses based mini game is printing the bullet twice

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ncurses

I'm developing a micro-game in c using the ncurses library for the front-end.

I simplified the code to the minimum, the expected result should be a shuttle that periodically shoots **one bomb**.
The problem is that when the program runs, the **first shoot** is always **duplicated** then sometimes the problem occurs again.

There are 2 processes that communicate through a pipe.

Here is a minimal version of the program to highlight the error:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ENEMYSPRITE "()"
#define BOMB "#"

typedef struct {
  char * c;
  int x;
  int y;
  int oldx;
  int oldy;
}
pos;

void bombe(int pipeout, pos pos_enemy) {
  pos pos_bomba;
  pos_bomba.c = BOMB;
  pos_bomba.x = pos_enemy.x;
  pos_bomba.y = pos_enemy.y + 1;

  write(pipeout, & pos_bomba, sizeof(pos_bomba));

  while (1) {
    pos_bomba.oldy = pos_bomba.y;
    pos_bomba.oldx = pos_bomba.x;
    pos_bomba.y++;
    write(pipeout, & pos_bomba, sizeof(pos_bomba));
    usleep(150000);
  }
  _exit(0);
}

void gameBoard(int pipein) {
  pos pos_enemy, pos_bomba, readValue;

  while (1) {
    read(pipein, & readValue, sizeof(readValue));

    if (strcmp(readValue.c, BOMB) == 0) {
      mvaddstr(pos_bomba.oldy, pos_bomba.oldx, " "); // deleting the old bullet's position
      pos_bomba = readValue;
    }
    mvaddstr(readValue.y, readValue.x, readValue.c);
    refresh();
  }
}

void enemy(int pipeout) {
  pid_t pid_bomba;
  pos pos_enemy;
  pos_enemy.c = ENEMYSPRITE;
  pos_enemy.x = 10;
  pos_enemy.y = 5;

  write(pipeout, & pos_enemy, sizeof(pos_enemy));

  while (1) {
    pid_bomba = fork();
    if (pid_bomba == 0) {
      bombe(pipeout, pos_enemy);
    }

    write(pipeout, & pos_enemy, sizeof(pos_enemy));
    usleep(1000000);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  initscr();
  noecho();
  curs_set(0);

  int fdescriptor[2];
  pipe(fdescriptor);
  pid_t pidEnemy = fork();
  if (pidEnemy == 0) {
    close(fdescriptor[0]);
    enemy(fdescriptor[1]);
  } else {
    close(fdescriptor[1]);
    gameBoard(fdescriptor[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to replace the `ncurses` output in `gameBoard` with text output of all values in the received structure, remove all other `ncurses` related function calls and check if the received data is what you expect and what `ncurses` function calls would result from the data. Maybe make the program a bit slower or let the loops terminate after a certain number of cycles. Also check the return value of all function calls, especially `read` and `write`. I suggest to add the PID of the sending process to the structure type `pos` and print it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with our code is inside function `bombe()`. Here is the revision that fixed the problem of initially it shoots twice.

```
void bombe(int pipeout, pos pos_enemy) {
    pos pos_bomba = pos_enemy;
    pos_bomba.c = BOMB;
    pos_bomba.y = pos_enemy.y + 1;

    while (1) {
        pos_bomba.oldy = pos_bomba.y;
        pos_bomba.oldx = pos_bomba.x;
        write(pipeout, & pos_bomba, sizeof(pos_bomba));

        ++pos_bomba.y;

        usleep(1155000);
    }
  _exit(0);
}
```

Note that now only one `write()` inside this function.